# How can I draw a trajectory of an orbit?

Tags: godot, gdscript, trajectory

With the following code, I either get a straight line or no line at all. I have tried almost the same thing in Unity and I get something that looks like orbiting, but here I get nothing.

How can I fix my code to draw a trajectory?

```gdscript
func _update_trajectory(delta):
    line.clear_points()
    var line_points = []
    var pos = mousePosition
    
    #starting velocity 200 for now
    var xAxis=200
    var yAxis =200
    
    var vel = Vector2(0,100)
    var vecR = sunGravity.position-pos
    var gravityForce = (vecR).normalized()
    var angle= 0
    
    
    var lastPos = pos +velocity.normalized()
    for i in range(1,MAX_POINTS-1):
        line_points.append(pos)
        
        vel+=Rigidbody_test(pos)
        lastPos=pos
        pos += vel*delta
        
    line.points=line_points 

func Rigidbody_test(pos1:Vector2):
   var planetPos = sunGravity.position
   var dir=planetPos-pos1
   var dis = dir.length_squared()
   var forceMag=2*g_constant*((sunGravity.mass*currentMass)/dis)
   var force =dir.normalized()*forceMag
   return force
```

Comment: It looks like your last edit introduced an error - you start the `_update_trajectory` function, but the lines under it are not indented as expected (or you're missing the `pass` statement). Regarding the problem, how are you drawing line? Does the inspector show the contents/points of the line changing?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue by increasing gravity constant so instead of having 0.0006 or whatever I just increased it to something like 274 which actually showed the curvature.